# Why does a linear mapping take vectors from the rowspace of matrix A to its column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I understand that a linear transformation $A$ projects a given vector $x$ to its column space $C(A)$. But why do people say that $A$ projects vectors from its row space $R(A)$?

Is there a similar interpretation that explains why for any $x$ in $Ax$ it must be true that $x \in R(A)$? Ideally, is there a direct/constructive way to show this? (Instead of just arguing that the dimensions match).

Comment: “Project” might not be the best chose of term here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case: consider the following matrix,

$$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, $Me_1 = (1,0,0)$ wich is **not** in $R(M) = \langle (1,1,0) \rangle$.

Comment: Uhm now I'm confused, I thought that by the fundamental theorem of linear algebra, for any matrix $A: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ it takes any vector from $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and projects it onto $Im(A)$, and that $U$ from which we take $x$ factors into $R(A)$ (rowspace) and $Ker(A)$, such that $R(A) \cup Ker(A) = U$?

Comment: If you could specify what you mean by the fundamental theorem of linear algebra (where I'm from we don't have such convention) I can add some additional comments to clarify.

Comment: This is what I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra ... it basically describes the dimenions and relationships of the four subspaces of a matrix, rowspace ($R(A)$), kernel (nullspace $Ker(A)$), column space (image $C(A)$ or $Im(A)$), and left nullspace ($Ker(A^T)$)

Comment: Okay, so, you're correct when you say that $Ax$ will lie on the column space. This is because each canonical vector verifies $Ae_i = C_i$, the $i$-th column of $A$, and so if $x = \sum_{i}\alpha_ie_i$, $$Ax = \sum_{i}\alpha_iCA_ei = \sum_{i}\alpha_iC_i \in C(A)$$. As for the domain of the function, as the page you've linked states, we can decompose it as $ker(A) \oplus ker(A)^\perp = ker(A) \oplus im(A^t)$, with the latter being the column space of $A^t$ or equivalently, the row space of $A$. Therefore each $x$ in the domain is some vector in the null space plus some vector in the row space.

Comment: In the example I gave, $(1,0,0) = \frac{1}{2}(1,-1,0) +\frac{1}{2}(1,1,0)$ with the first being in the null space of $M$, and the latter in $R(M)$.

Comment: Ok great, I understand now that my mistake was to assume that the domain was $R(M)$ while in reality it is $R(M) \cup Ker(M)$. I'm still confused though how one gets to $R(M)$? Do we just derive somehow that the domain must be $Im(A^T) \cup Ker(A)$ and from that say $Im(A^T) = R(A)$? I'm having trouble intuitively undertsanding what $R(A)$ is, other than it being an ortogonal complement of $Ker(A)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79624/discussion-between-guido-a-and-jakub-arnold).